# Linking a 3rd party library (Sybase Ultralite) into MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop

We need to port a Windows Mobile 6 application to the iPhone, and as our developers have experience in C#, MonoTouch is the perfect platform.

We have to use an Ultralite database in our iPhone application, a management decision, and if we can't get this working, we will be forced to develop the application with Xcode and Objective-C. How do I link 3rd party libraries into MonoTouch?

I have built a small sample application in xCode and Objective-C which demonstrates the use of the Ultralite library. The steps that I followed in setting up this sample application are laid out here (Lessons 1 to 4):

dcx.sybase.com/index.html#1200en/ulc/ulc-create-new-iphone-app-project.html

All I need is a starting point, and this sample application running in MonoTouch will give me that. I want to convert this sample application to run on MonoTouch. The sample application can be found here:

https://github.com/BruceHill/Ultralite-Names-Sample-ObjC

Comment: Your compiler error on the forums is a mismatch between MonoTouch and iOS SDK versions.  There are several samples using native libraries on github.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mismatch, Geoff. There was indeed a mismatch; I now have iOS SDK 4.2 installed and my test application at least compiles now. :) So I am a step further. I will search on github for samples of using native libraries. Thanks.